# divs not showing update to object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object-literal

I've got a nested object literal that looks like this.

```
goals = {
  "691473a7-acad-458e-bb27-96bac22467jj": {
    category: "personal",
    datecreated: "2013-10-20",
    goal: "brush teeth--morning",
    icon: "health",
    status: "completed",
    repeat: "no",
    username: "jimmysmith",
    userguid: "0c7270bd-38e8-4db2-ae92-244de019c543"
  },
  "9e693231-e6d8-4ca9-b5c8-81ea7a8056hh": {
    category: "personal",
    datecreated: "2013-10-20",
    goal: "track spending money",
    icon: "dollar",
    status: "inprogress",
    username: "jimmysmith",
    userguid: "0c7270bd-38e8-4db2-ae92-244de019c543"
  },
  "8d23005d-f6f3-4589-bb85-a90510bc45gg": {
    category: "personal",
    datecreated: "2013-10-20",
    goal: "Brush teeth--night",
    icon: "health",
    status: "inprogress",
    username: "jimmysmith",
    userguid: "0c7270bd-38e8-4db2-ae92-244de019c543"
  }
};
```

I can get the contents to properly display on the page with this:

```
displayMyGoalList = function() {
  var completedHTML, inprogressHTML, missedHTML;
  completedHTML = [];
  inprogressHTML = [];
  missedHTML = [];
  $.each(goals, function(index, goal) {
    if (goal.userguid === userguid) {
      if (goal.category === goalCategory) {
        console.log(goal.goal + '  ' + goal.status);
        if (goal.status === 'completed') {
          return completedHTML.push('<li class="' + goal.status + '" data-userguid="' + goal.userguid + '" data-goalguid="' + index + '"><span class="goaltitle"><i class="fa-large icon-' + goal.icon + '"></i> ' + goal.goal + '</span><span class="goalstatus" data-goal="' + goal.goal + '"><input type="checkbox" checked></span><span class="goalremove"><button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger removegoal" data-removegoal="' + goal.goalguid + '"><b>X</b> </button></span><span class="chartbutton"><i class="fa-large icon-stats" ></i></span></li>');
        } else if (goal.status === 'inprogress') {
          return inprogressHTML.push('<li class="' + goal.status + '" data-userguid="' + goal.userguid + '" data-goalguid="' + index + '"><span class="goaltitle"><i class="fa-large icon-' + goal.icon + '"></i> ' + goal.goal + '</span><span class="goalstatus" data-goal="' + goal.goal + '"><input type="checkbox" ></span><span class="goalremove"><button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger removegoal" data-removegoal="' + goal.goalguid + '"><b>X</b> </button></span><span class="chartbutton"><i class="fa-large icon-stats" ></i></span></li>');
        } else {
          return missedHTML.push('<li class="' + goal.status + '" data-userguid="' + goal.userguid + '" data-goalguid="' + index + '"><span class="goaltitle"><i class="fa-large icon-' + goal.icon + '"></i> ' + goal.goal + '</span><span class="goalstatus" data-goal="' + goal.goal + '"><input type="checkbox" ></span><span class="goalremove"><button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger removegoal" data-removegoal="' + goal.goalguid + '"><b>X</b> </button></span><span class="chartbutton"><i class="fa-large icon-stats" ></i></span></li>');
        }
      }
    }
  });
  $(".goalsinprogress").html(inprogressHTML.join(""));
  $(".goalscompleted").html(completedHTML.join(""));
  $(".goalsmissed").html(missedHTML.join(""));
  return $(".goalsection").css({
    visibility: "visible"
  }).fadeIn(200);
};
```

I can correctly add a new goal object to the nested literal, but the html divs won't show that new goal.

```
$('#savegoal').click(function() {
  datecreated = new Date().toString();
  goals = JSON.parse(localStorage["goals"]);
  goalguid = createGuid();
  goals[goalguid] = {
    status: "inprogress",
    category: $("#thecategory").val(),
    goal: $("#thegoal").val(),
    icon: $("input[name=icon]:checked").val(),
    datecreated: datecreated,
    userguid: userguid,
    username: username,
    recurring: $("input[name=days]:checked").val(),
    infotype: $("input[name=theinfotype]:checked").val()
  };
  localStorage.setItem("goals", JSON.stringify(goals));
  $("#addgoalform").hide();
  $('#thegoal').val('');
  $('#theicon input').removeAttr('checked');
  $('#infotype input').removeAttr('checked');
  $('#daysoftheweek input').removeAttr('checked');
  logSummary();
  return displayMyGoalList();
});
```

I've run console.log in several places around the each in the display function, and all the objects show up. But they're not making it into the join. Any ideas?

I've tried to empty the divs with .html('') and with .empty() before the redraw, but that doesn't make a difference.

Thanks much,
Charlie Magee

Comment: Try to debug each array with console.log and see its content

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with some mock-up html so I can see what's going on?

Comment: Also, where is `var goals`?  At first I thought jQuery might be ignoring your `.html()` due to a syntax error in the string, but they all check out.  The only other thing I can think of off the top of my head is `goals` not referring to the same object due to scope.

Comment: I ran console.log everywhere that made sense. No scoping problems. goals is showing the correct nested objects before and after creating the new goal. I probably won't be able to build the fiddle soon. I'm supposed to be picking up groceries for Thanksgiving dinner.

Comment: Here's a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/charliemagee/MxV5P/2/  My apologies, it's very messy due to missing fonts and css not vital to the test. You need to add a new student to initialize the preexisting students and then their data. Then click Add Goal to add a goal and see that it is not showing up in the list. The displayMyGoalList function on line 557 works correctly on the user click function (521), but not after the savegoal function (491). Console log shows all goals before the each function (inside displayMyGoalList), but does not show the new ones within the each.

Comment: If you choose the "School" category when making a new goal it's supposed to show up in the current view as one of the items with a blue background.

Answer (score 0):

Well this belongs in the category of stupid. And explains why no one picked it up in trying to comment or answer.

I suppose it's worth having here as a reminder. My issue was hidden, yet obvious. My $.each was working fine. It all came down to an uppercase/lowercase issue. My code was looking for a string called 'school' but my function was capturing a value that was 'School'.

All I had to do in my savegoal function was to change this

```
category: $("#thecategory").val(),
```

to this

```
category: $("#thecategory").val().toLowerCase(),
```